# How to build an interpreter for a small language?

Tags: java, c++, interpreter

I'm trying to figure out where to start with this project. Perhaps someone can steer me in the right direction.

I am given a small language that I must write an interpreter for. The language consists of either an expression in parentheses:

```
(integer integer operator)
```

or an arithmetic IF statement made up of expressions in the form:

```
IF exp1 exp2 exp3 exp4
```

where exp2 is returned if exp1 is negative,
exp3 is returned if exp1 is zero,
and exp4 is returned if exp1 is positive.

The operator is either + or x (for addition and multiplication respectively).

I have to implement a scanner/parser together, then the interpreter that will output the result. The interpreter part will not be difficult, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to start the scanning/parsing process.

I have started by using Java, and have a Scanner object collect the input and store it in a string. Then I split the String into a String array using nothing as the delimiter (so that each single character, symbol, space, etc. is stored in its own index of a string). This may not be the best way to do this, as I cannot figure out where to go from here.  The part I cannot grasp is how to return errors if this syntax isn't followed, or how to detect the parenthesis and/or IF and etc.

Here's the snippet of code that I described in the last paragraph:

```
public void run() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String sLine = sc.nextLine();
        String[] scanned = sLine.split("");
```

Input examples:

```
(7 2 +)

Output: 9

IF (2 -2 +) (5 2 +) (5 -2 x) (5 2 x)

Output: -10
```

If anybody has a good direction for me to take, please share. :)

Comment: If you are using Java, then I recommend [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

Comment: Once you sort the basics, maybe you can look into implementing a [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).

Comment: I'd recommend starting with a book on compilers (the first few steps are nearly identical between "interpreters" and "compilers"). While the "Dragon" book is highly recommended, there are many gentler resources as well. Consider also looking for Undergradutate-level Course Material. Being lazy, I prefer Recursive Descent Parsers ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using ANTLR, JavaCC, SampleCC or other parser generator tools would be using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. if there is no recursion in grammar definition just a few methods would be sufficient. the following code gives a basic idea (it may not compile or work, I wrote it from scratch as an illustration how to start):

```
public int parse(String input) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

    return consumeLine(scanner);
}

public int consumeLine(Scanner scanner) {
    if( scanner.hasNext("(") ) {
        return consumeExpression(scanner);

    } else if( scanner.hasNext("IF") ) {
        return consumeIf(scanner);
    }
}


public int consumeExpression(Scanner scanner) {
    scanner.next("(");
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    int b = scanner.nextInt();
    String op = scanner.next("[+-/*]");
    scanner.next(")");

    if( "+".equals(op) ) {
        return a + b;

    } else if( "-".equals(op) ) {
        return a - b;
    } ...

    throw new RuntimeException("parsing error");
}

public int consumeIf(Scanner scanner) {
    scanner.next("IF");
    int exp1 = consumeExpression(scanner);
    int exp2 = consumeExpression(scanner);
    int exp3 = consumeExpression(scanner);
    int exp4 = consumeExpression(scanner);

    if( exp1 < 0 ) {
        return exp2;
    } else if( exp1 == 0 ) {
        return exp3;
    } ...

    throw new RuntimeException("should not be here (TM)");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I manipulated your code a bit, and it seems it SHOULD work, but every time I try to use hasNext() or next() with a parenthesis as the argument, I get a regex syntax error.  Any clue how to test for a "(" properly?

Comment: @Rationalist ah indeed I forgot scanner.next() takes a regexp rather than simple string. just use "\(" and "\)"

Answer (score 4):

You can use stack based algorithms to process postfix expressions. 
A simple idea would be to push integers on a stack and when you encounter a operator , pop the integers from stack and perform the operation mentioned by the operator like + , - .

Comment: Thank you for at least giving me some advice on the interpreter.  I do believe I have figured out the scanner/parser part on my own.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy with javacc if you are into java. You can mention your tokens and what to do with them in a compact and easy way, then when it is compiled it generates all the code in java source required to perform the logic.

[javacc intro](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-cooltools.html)

[javacc faq](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use C++ and the boost spirit library....

Comment: @PragneshChauhan: it addresses "how to build an interpreter for a small language" and "If anybody has a good direction for me to take, please share" - it leaves The Rationalist to do the reading to understand why that would help him or her.  A half hour perusal of the spirit documentation would explain exactly how that library handles the specific issues mentioned in the question.  I provide this as an "answer" rather than a comment, so people who agree spirit is a particularly promising direction can indicate agreement relative to the other proposals.