# What do I need to learn to build an interpreter?

Tags: programming-languages, interpreter, interpreted-language

For my AQA A2-level Computing project, I've decided to create a basic interpreted programming language, outputting to Console. I don't know how to build an interpreter. I have a copy of the [purple dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition), which is all about compiler design, as user166390 said on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596698/how-to-build-an-interpreter-for-a-small-language) that the initial steps to building a compiler are the same to build an interpreter. My question is: is this true?

Can I use the techniques described in the dragon book to write an interpreter? And if so, which steps do I need to use and learn how to use?

Do I need to write a lexical analyser, a syntax analyser, a semantic analyser and an intermediate code generator, for example?

Could I get away with writing a basic parser that reads each line of the source code, parses it, and executes the instruction straight away, or is that a notoriously bad idea?

Comment: Difference between compilers and interpreters is vague. Probably the simplest approach is to build a compiler from your source language into a bytecode of a virtual machine designed with both ease of compilation and runtime performance in mind. There is a lot of literature on VM design available. Most of the modern interpreters (like CPython, Perl6, etc.) are implemented this way. What you can omit from a compiler is complex optimisations and native code generation (i.e., the most complicated parts of compilation).

Comment: I was given the impression that compiler design was a lot more complicated than an interpreter design - given the limited scope and time of this project, I want to go for the simpler route. Plus I've been told that interpreters are easier for debugging, and the principle aim is to make a language that is simple and easy to use for non-programmers. If it's easier to debug, the better.

Comment: As @SK-logic notes, the distinction between a compiler and an interpreter isn't clear-cut.  Rather than talking about a compiler versus an interpreter, tell us instead what features you need from a code-executor that you would not get if you just wrote a normal compiler.  Then we can tell you what changes are necessary to incorporate those features.

Comment: Interpreters are in fact more complicated than compilers. With an ad hoc interpreter you have to implement complete operational semantics for your high level, likely quite non-trivial language. Even such a simple thing as lexical scoping is tricky with interpreters. Compilation is different - it is all about transforming trees, one simple step at a time, from a complex language into a much simpler one. And then you can interpret your simple language (e.g., a flat bytecode of an abstract machine) easily.

Comment: An interpreter can only be simpler than a compiler if the language to be interpreted lends itself more easily to being interpreted (usually this means "*single-line at-a-time compilation and execution*").  So it's really the language design that makes it simpler (or other reduced functionality).

Comment: The difficulty here is that I don't know or understand a lot of these concepts and so can't answer your questions as well as I'd like. I would like the language to be, as RBarryYoung describes, "single-line at-a-time compilation and execution".

Comment: I would highly suggst you look up lex and yacc (or flex and bison). These are very powerfull tools.

Comment: @SK-logic re: Difference between compilers and interpreters is vague Is a bit misleading in as far as they are clearly defined differences that have existed for as long as computing has been around. An interpreter looks at a program line by line, a compiled language is a file that can run without need to be interpreted as the computer already has everything it needs in a format it understands all under one hood.

Comment: @MarkGiblin, only the most primitive ad hoc interpreters (such as csh, for example) look at the source "line by line".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the techniques described in the dragon book to write an interpreter.

You need a lexical analyzer and a parser regardless.

As others have pointed out, you do need to write the code to do actual execution -- but for a simple interpreter, this can be essentially the same as the [syntax-directed translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax-directed_translation) described in the dragon book.

Everything else is optional.

---

If you want to skip straight from the parser to execution, you can.  That will leave you with a very simple language, which can be both good and bad -- look at [Tcl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) for an example of such a language.

If you want to interpret each line as you parse it, you can do that, too; this is what most command-line interpreters (Unix shell scripts, Microsoft's cmd.com and PowerShell) do, as well as interactive "REPL's" (Read-Eval-Print-Loops) for languages like Python and Ruby.

"Semantic analyzer" seems vague to me, but sounds like it should include most kinds of load-time consistency checks.  This is also optional, but there are advantages in an interpreter that won't take any old garbage and try to execute it as a program...

"Intermediate code" is also kind of vague, but it is arguably optional.  If you aren't executing directly from the program string (as in Tcl), you need some kind of internal representation to store your code once you've read it in.  One popular option is to execute from an internal tree structure, based more or less closely on your parse tree, which is arguably distinct from producing "intermediate code".  On the other hand, if your "intermediate code" could be written out more or less directly from your internal tree structure, you might as well count the internal structure as your "intermediate code".

---

There are important issues that you haven't addressed; one that stands out is:  how do you want to handle names?  Presumably you will want the programmer to be able to define and use his own names (e.g., for variables, functions, and so forth), so you will need to implement some kind of mechanism for that.

Exactly how names are handled is a big design decision, with major implications for the usability and implementability of your language.  The simplest option for implementation is to use a single, global hash map to implement a single, global namespace -- but note that this choice has well-known usability problems...

Answer (score 1):

> Could I get away with writing a basic parser that reads source code and executes the steps straight away?

You could but you'd be doing it the hard way.

> Do I need to write a lexical analyser, a syntax analyser, a semantic analyser and an intermediate code generator, for example?

You can skip intermediate code generation except if you want to write a VM-based interpreter. Perl for example, used to execute its parse graph directly; this is in contrast with Java or Python, which produces intermediate byte code.

The interpreter part of a VM-based language is generally simpler than the interpreter that have to understand a parse graph (so each component in the system is simpler), however the complexity of the whole interpreter  stack is generally simpler when you don't need to define an intermediate bytecode language. So pick your poison.

Comment: I don't want to write a VM-based interpreter, assuming VM stands for Virtual Machine. When you say "parse graph", is this synonymous with "parse tree", and is this part of syntax analysis?

Comment: What do you mean by interpreter stack? Isn't bytecode for languages that are neither strictly compiled nor interpreted? I apologise for all the questions, I'm evidently inexperienced and don't understand a lot of these concepts.

Comment: sorry to confuse you, yes, parse graph is the same as a parse tree (it's just a pedantically more correct term because the "parse tree" of most languages is not strictly speaking a "tree"). By interpreter stack, I mean the whole language project (including any preprocessor, parser, code generator, VM/interpreter, etc). A parse graph interpreter had to be aware of the structure of the program, while bytecode interpreter wouldn't need to (and thus can be much simpler).